# WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, junit4

In my program I have a Java method which access MSSql server 2008 DB and update some table in it
When I am try to run this method,I am getting this error

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I have added sqljdbc_auth.dll into windows/system32 folder
TCP/IP connection are enabled in MSSql server 2008 console
Added the path in environment settings

**System requirement**:
Window 7- 64bit

Whether this error is due to 32 bit/64 bit conflict?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your libpath and system path are set
You need to make sure the JVM you use matches the DLL you try to load.  ie if you use a 32bit JVM use 32bit drivers, if you use a 64bit jvm, use 64bit drivers.

I think this is a pretty good tutorial:
http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/connecting-to-sql-server-from-java/

Comment: Iam using 64 bit JVM and 64 bit driver dll and i have set my libpath and system path  but still am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `java.libary.path` system property to specify the directory of the `sqljdbc_auth.dll`. For example, if the JDBC driver is installed in the default directory, you can specify the location of the DLL by using the following virtual machine (VM) argument when the Java application is started:

```
-Djava.library.path=c:/sqljdbc_<version>/enu/auth/x86
```

or

```
-Djava.library.path=c:/sqljdbc_<version>/enu/auth/x64
```